# Position sticky is not working used inside grid

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, css-position

On a particular offset value or section entry, I need to make the card a sticky card (which is having an id "sticky Card") that exist in a particular grid column of the grid container. I am using offset `y` value to add condition when the card needs to be sticky. Let me know of any possibilities. As of now, sticky is not working inside `container&grid`

```
if (window.pageYOffset > 1500 && window.pageYOffset < 2000) {
  document.getElementById("stickyCard").style.position = "sticky";
  document.getElementById("stickyCard").style.top = "100px"; 
  document.getElementById("stickyCard").style.zIndex = "1"; 

}  else{
  document.getElementById("stickyCard").style.position = "relative";
  document.getElementById("stickyCard").style.top = "0px"; 
  document.getElementById("stickyCard").style.right = "0px"; 
  document.getElementById("stickyCard").style.zIndex = 0;

}




<div name="key-features"> 
    <Box
      component="section"
      className={classes.root}
      paddingY={8}
      mx="auto"
    >
      <Container maxWidth="lg"> 
          <Grid container spacing={2} direction="row">
            <Grid item xs={9}>
              <Typography
                variant="h2"
                className={classes.heading}
                gutterBottom
                component="h2"
                align="left"
              >
                {data.heading}
              </Typography>

              <div className={classes.grideRoot}>
                <Grid container spacing={4}>
                  {data.trainingList.map((item, index) => (
                    <Grid
                      key={index}
                      item
                      item
                      xs={12}
                      sm={6}
                      md={4}
                      lg={4}
                    >
                      <TrainingOverViewCard data={item} />
                    </Grid>
                  ))}
                </Grid>
              </div>
            </Grid>

            <Grid
              item
              xs={3} 
            >
              <Grid
                container
                direction="column"
                justify="center"
                alignItems="center"
              >
                <div id="stickyCard">
                  <SelectedScheduleBanner />
                  {/* <RequestCallBackCard/> */}
                </div>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>  
      </Container> 
    </Box> 
</div>
```

Comment: Why have you stripped relevant code from your question?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)